# Can I ground/discharge myself with an iMac, or with cookware, or any metal in the house/office?

Tags: computer-building

I am building my computer later. I want to know if touching an iMac or a steel cookware would be the same as touching a bare metal part of the computer case. I'm asking because my case is fully painted. I want to know if I can "ground" or "discharge" myself using any metal apart from the computer case itself.

Comment: It's not the same and there are bare metal spots on any system (like screws or internal sheet metal).

Comment: so touching screws would work? But I have thumbscrews, so even that slight bare part where you put the screws would work?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a desktop PC with a metal case.  Any bare metal portion of the case, or bare screws or brackets fastened to the case will work.  If it has something like a plastic front, and screws that fasten one plastic part to another without fastening to the case, those wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works properly if the machine is connected to a grounded mains socket [with the power off]
Otherwise you may be in equilibrium with that device, yet not necessarily with anything else.

And vice-versa - it's no good grounding yourself through the cooker/iMac if the new device isn't also at the same potential.

Once you have satisfied that requirement, then any bare metal part of the case will suffice - even if you just put a spare screw in an as-yet unused hole; the threaded part of the hole is unlikely to have been painted after the thread was tapped.

Comment: Do I really need to screw a screw in or can I just touch the threaded part?

Comment: Any method you like, so long as you get a clean connection. Though as the threaded porting is inside the case, it's going to be pretty hard to touch by any other method.